# Getting pivot values with far relations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, has-many-through

In my Laravel project I've used the following ([inspired from here](https://softonsofa.com/laravel-querying-any-level-far-relations-with-simple-trick/)) to get a far relation from a model to another. I can't use the [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) method since the **bars** and **bazs** are related with a polymorphic relation.

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public function foos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Foo');
    }

    public function getBazAttribute()
    {
        $this->load(['foos.bars.bazs' => function ($q) use (&$bazs) {
            $bazs = $q->get()->unique();
        }]);
    }
}
```

This works as expected and returns the **bazs** that are related to the **bars** that are related to the **foos** that are related to the **MyClass object**. My problem is that I don't know how I can use this to easily get things such as:

- The specific **foos** that each **baz** relates to
- The total number of **foos** that each **baz** relates to

*Note: The list of **foos** returned must be the **foos** that the **bazs** are related to the **bar** through*

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer for both question in one way.

The easiest way will be probably load `foos` with eager load - but in the opposit way - on `$bazs` collection:

```
$bazs->load('bars.foos');
```

And define for example Accessor's method in baz's model:

```
public function getFoosAttribute()
{
    $foos = \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::make([]);
    foreach ($this->bars as $bar) {
        $foos->merge($bar->foos);
    }
    return $foos;
}
```

Now, when You have them all loaded You can itterate over then and use somehowe the results of foos collections:

```
foreach ($bazs as $baz) {
    // get all baz's foos way
    $foosOfBaz = $baz->foos;

    //when we have them all in collection we can easily count them
    $foosOfBaz->count() 
}
```

> The list of foos returned must be the foos that the bazs are related
>   to the bar through

If You want to get foos related to the baz through the specific bar You  can only access through nested for/foreach loop, becasue both of the relation level (bazs and it's bars) are in collection:

```
$bazs->load('bars.foos');

foreach ($bazs as $baz) {
    foreach ($baz->bars as $bar) {
        //here You can access the foos collection 
        //that is from bar's that belongs to baz model's object
        $bar->foos;
    }
}
```

*Note: if toy want to get an array You have to to it with: `$bar->foos->toArray()` or use `->pluck('filed_name', 'key_name')->toArray()` method for a simple  list*

Comment: Almost, I know this wasn't clear in the question (which I've now updated) but from the **bazs** that relates to the **bar** through the **foo** I only want the list of **foos** that it relates to the **bazs** through.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve such long relations using Foreign Keys too. I have experienced this many times in huge projects. Let me explain below :

One way to Solve would be.

```
Table A    Table B    Table C    Table D
  1           a          x         I 
  2           b          y         II
  3           c          z         III
```

Let says here you have table A linked to table B and table B to table C and table C to table D.

If you want to fetch data that requires table A and D only and has nothing to do with the intermediate table. You can create a Foreign Key relation in D that directly connects to table A.

Below is an example from one of my project that had long relationship.

[image: This is one of my project that had long relationship]
Here if you see If I need to calculate the sum of all score for a given user, which I need to put in the leaderboards. I dont want to go through tournaments and get the score. I can directly calculate by adding foreign key to the table. I dont think its a bad practice. As I normally create such relationships by keeping front-end model in my mind. It will make querying lot easier.

I might have not given the solution that you needed but a different approach you could use to solve a problem. But wanted to share a solution that I normally use to tackle such problem.